# Somar números de várias Strings em PHP

Tags: php, string

Como faço para somar os números de várias Strings em PHP, como por exemplo:

```
string(2) "66" string(1) "5"
```

Desejo obter o resultado de 66 + 5 = 71.

Comment: Com o operador `+` ou `array_sum`

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode fazer a soma da seguinte forma.

```
<?php
$a = '66';
$b = '5';
$soma = $a + $b;
echo $soma;
//exibe 71
?>
```

Agora, se você pretende somar números decimais, a história é diferente.

Recomendo neste caso utilizar funções matemáticas do PHP:
[bcadd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php)

```
<?php
echo PHP_EOL;
$a = '0.66';
$b = '0.05';
$soma = bcadd($a, $b, 2);
echo $soma;
//exibe 0.71
?>
```

Aqui tem um artigo em inglês explicando o problema:
[don-t-trust-php-floating-point-numbers-when-equating](https://andy-carter.com/blog/don-t-trust-php-floating-point-numbers-when-equating)